# how to union, intersection, set-difference and cross-product for xml document?

Tags: xml

I have three files xml:

instance S1 from sailors (S1.xml):

```
<xml>
     <data>
       <sid>22</sid>
       <sname>Dustin</sname>
       <rating>7</rating>
       <age>45</age>
     </data>
      <data>
       <sid>31</sid>
       <sname>Lubber</sname>
       <rating>8</rating>
       <age>55</age>
     </data>
      <data>
       <sid>58</sid>
       <sname>Rusty</sname>
       <rating>10</rating>
       <age>35</age>
     </data>
</xml>
```

instance S2 from sailors (S2.xml):

```
 <xml>
     <data>
       <sid>28</sid>
       <sname>Yuppy</sname>
       <rating>9</rating>
       <age>35</age>
     </data>
      <data>
       <sid>31</sid>
       <sname>Lubber</sname>
       <rating>8</rating>
       <age>55</age>
     </data>
      <data>
       <sid>44</sid>
       <sname>Gruppy</sname>
       <rating>5</rating>
       <age>35</age>
     </data>
     <data>
       <sid>58</sid>
       <sname>Rusty</sname>
       <rating>10</rating>
       <age>35</age>
     </data>
</xml>
```

instance R1 from Reserves (R1.xml):

```
 <xml>
     <data>
       <sid>22</sid>
       <bid>101</bid>
       <day>10/10/96</day>
     </data>
     <data>
       <sid>58</sid>
       <bid>103</bid>
       <day>11/12/96</day>
     </data>
</xml>
```

im trying to use operator algebra for the xml file like : union (∪), intersection (∩), set-difference (-), and cross-product (×)

im trying search S1 ∪ S2, S1 ∩S2, S1-S2, S1 X R1

for example im trying to make new document consisting of S1 ∪ S2 like :

```
<xml>
     <data>
       <sid>22</sid>
       <sname>Dustin</sname>
       <rating>7</rating>
       <age>45</age>
     </data>
      <data>
       <sid>31</sid>
       <sname>Lubber</sname>
       <rating>8</rating>
       <age>55</age>
     </data>
      <data>
       <sid>58</sid>
       <sname>Rusty</sname>
       <rating>10</rating>
       <age>35</age>
     </data>
     <data>
       <sid>28</sid>
       <sname>Yuppy</sname>
       <rating>9</rating>
       <age>35</age>
     </data>
     <data>
       <sid>44</sid>
       <sname>Gruppy</sname>
       <rating>5</rating>
       <age>35</age>
     </data>
</xml>
```

anyone can help me please ??
i'm trying using XSLT..

thanks..

best regards,

Rijal

Comment: What language do you use? Also, what's R1 - there's S2 twice?

Comment: @choroba im triying using xslt, can i do that ?
Sorry buddy, im mistakenly written.. :)
i have correct my question..

Answer (score 1):

There are example functions that perform these operations (using XSLT 2.0 or XQuery 1.0) in the W3C functions and operators specification at

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#union-intersect-except-on-values

For example set difference is coded in XQuery as:

```
declare function eg:value-except (
  $arg1 as xs:anyAtomicType*,
  $arg2 as xs:anyAtomicType*) as xs:anyAtomicType* 
{
  fn:distinct-values($arg1[not(.=$arg2)])
}
```

Comment: can you teach me how to solve my problem using implementation XSLT..?
actually, I am a beginner and have just learned XSLT..
thanks before..

Comment: StackOverflow is for answering specific technical questions, not for teaching. If you want teaching, I've written a book....

Comment: how can i look your book ?

Comment: XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference, 4th edition, published by Wiley, easily available from Amazon or other online stores.

Comment: can you give me please example how intersection file xml using XSLT ?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained your requirement very clearly. But if your requirement is to find all the `<data>` elements appearing in both S1.xml and S2.xml, and if a matching `<sid>` is enough to treat the data elements as matching, and if there are no duplicates within a single file, then the simplest solution in XSLT 2.0 is

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="doc('S1.xml')//data, doc('S2.xml')//data"
  group-by="sid">
  <xsl:copy-of select=".[count(current-group()) = 2]"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```